# Excel or VBA to subtract values on list with duplicate ID according to stock

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have list of IDs with warehouse stocks and list of shipments to customers which might have same ID.

Attached screen with example, so for 29.08.2022 with hour 08:00 we need to have 100 carrots, on warehouse we have 375pcs = 275pcs are left. Then few hours later we have shipment to other customer which requires 500pcs of carrots, 275-500 = -225pcs -> it shows info we need to harvest that much more untill 11:00.

1. needed vlookup for value from stock
2. then subtract every repeated value from top to bottom

[carrots example screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxLOu.png)

Looking for formula or vba which could handle this calculation without manual addition of many columns - currently I have something done with countif for as much as 10 duplicate ID - it just adds "1-"&ID then subtract this and takes it as "2-"&ID.. etc. It's very slow on performance.

As for VBA there is probably no possibility to dynamically declare ID from range as variable from stocks and then simply subtract in loop?

Comment: I cannot understand your question... What "stock after ship" should mean? Not the quantity remained after shipping on the same line? If so, what to be calculated? Should we count only on the first such operation per each item? Where from did you deduce/calculate the initial stock for carrot as 375? Just reversing the operation looking logical? 375 + 100? If so, what the figures on the next lines for the same item do represent? How could you physically ship 500 pieces, if the remained stock was only 275 after the first shipment? Aren't they shipments, are only programed shipments?

Comment: It may have been planned to have 1000pcs but only 375 were put in stock. So you have 375pcs in stock, then deduct 100pcs for first shipment, and I want to have shown next missing quantities.

Comment: I still do not understand anything from your question. I know how to process such data, but only if I understand what it shows and based on what logic to extract the necessary values. I wish you success in solving of the problem! I am not able to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work (paste in B2 and use autofill) :

`=VLOOKUP($B2,$K$3:$L$17,2,FALSE)-SUMIF(INDIRECT("$B$2:$B$" & ROW()),$B2,INDIRECT("$C$2:$C$" & ROW()))`

- `VLOOKUP($B2,$K$3:$L$17,2,FALSE)` return the stock value of the item of the current row (777 for row 2)
- `SUMIF(INDIRECT("$B$2:$B$" & ROW()),$B2,INDIRECT("$C$2:$C$" & ROW()))` return the sum of qty ship (of the current row and rows above) of the item of the current row (250 for row 2, 350 for row 5)

Comment: Genius! Works good :), thank you!

Answer (score 0):

what about simple sumifs formula like below?

```
=L3-SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,J3)
```

place in cell `M3` add drag/copy to the bottom